# PHP - Skip the first row of csv when importing to MySQL Database

Tags: php, csv

These codes import the contents of a CSV file to the database.

```
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "test";
$databasetable = "sample";
$databaseusername ="test";
$databasepassword = "";
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile = "filename.csv";
$addauto = 0;
$save = 1;
$outputfile = "output.sql";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";
    exit;
}

$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

if(!$file) {
    echo "Error opening data file.\n";
    exit;
}

$size = filesize($csvfile);

if(!$size) {
    echo "File is empty.\n";
    exit;
}

$csvcontent = fread($file,$size);

fclose($file);

$con = @mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$lines = 0;
$queries = "";
$linearray = array();

foreach(split($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

    $lines++;

    $line = trim($line," \t");

    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

    if($addauto)
        $query = "insert into $databasetable values('','$linemysql');";
    else
        $query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";

    $queries .= $query . "\n";

    @mysql_query($query);
}

@mysql_close($con);

if($save) {

    if(!is_writable($outputfile)) {
        echo "File is not writable, check permissions.\n";
    }
    else {
        $file2 = fopen($outputfile,"w");

        if(!$file2) {
            echo "Error writing to the output file.\n";
        }
        else {
            fwrite($file2,$queries);
            fclose($file2);
        }
    }

}

echo "Found a total of $lines records in this csv file.\n";
```

This is how it works.
The administrator will receive an excel spreadsheet (.xls) file and will save it as .csv file. And the first row of the file will be the 'headers' of the excel spreadsheet.
Example: Name, Email, Contact number, Country, Address headers.

So before importing the contents of the CSV file to the database, i want the first row to be skipped. Which means that the importing of contents will start at the second row of the CSV file.

May i know which part of codes should i edit and what should i edit it to?
Sorry, as i'm new to programming PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Please* stop using the outdated `mysql_` family of functions when writing new code.  Look into [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).  Also, please use the `@` error silencing operator sparingly.  It may be hiding errors in your code.

Comment: you may count to one. you know, it is not that hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little change will to the job. Before your `foreach` loop `split` your `$csvcontent` and safe the resulting array to `$allLines`. Then use `array_shift` to remove the 1st element of this array (the function also returns this element, but we don’t need it here):

```
$allLines = split($lineseparator,$csvcontent);
array_shift($allLines); // removes the 1st element

foreach($allLines as $line) {
    [...]
```

Comment: +1, nice solution, but you can with good conscience shorten it to (using the original code): `foreach(array_shift(split($lineseparator,$csvcontent)) as $line) {`

Comment: @zrvan: Your suggestion will not work, because `array_shift` returns the 1st element, not the shortened array.

Answer (score 3):

You are already working with a loop for each line. Just skip the first iteration:

```
$lines = 0;

foreach(split($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {
    $lines++;

    if($lines > 1){
        $line = trim($line," \t");
        $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);
        $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);

        $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

        $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

        if($addauto)
            $query = "insert into $databasetable values('','$linemysql');";
        else
            $query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";

        $queries .= $query . "\n";

        @mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: I spot a slight problem; `if($lines > 0){` will, in the current form, *always* evaluate to `true`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I changed it into `if($lines > 1){`, because with the first row, the variable will be incremented exactly one time. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm i edited at the same time, but i moved the lines++; to after the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$line_array = explode($csvcontent,$lineseparator);
$total_line = count($line_array);
for ($i=1;$i<$total_line;$i++){
    echo $line_array[$i] //it is your line play with this
}
```